# searching Text in Google Drive PDF files

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to search Text in pdf Files that are located on google drive by Google API in an own application?  If not, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can search for text in files by adding the `q` parameter to the request URL and using the `fullText` field, as in the following sample search query:

```
fullText contains 'hello'
```

For more details about the Google Drive query language check https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: The link seems to be outdates. The new link is https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#query_string_examples